# HTML Wrapper FDT

Tags: actionscript-3, fdt

I am working in as3 ide FDT. I want generate HTML wrapper for my flash project but I can t find any option which allows me to generate HTML wraper like in Flash Builder or Flash Profesional.

Where can I find it in FDT ?

Egid

Thank you in advance for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should answer your question:

[FDT Docs: From Flash Builder To FDT - Where's my html template and other support files?](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/From_Flash_Builder_To_FDT#Where.27s_my_html-template_and_other_support_files.3F)